# Extract POS number - iMacros

Tags: javascript, tags, imacros

I want to get the integer result from TAG POS=* when it matches the text 'Send a gift' from a very large list

My code is as below

```
        SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 8
        TAG POS=* TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send a gift
'
        SET {{EXTRACTED-POS-NUMBER-FROM-*}}
        TAG POS={{!EXTRACTED-POS-NUMBER-FROM-*}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:gift-list-message-action EXTRACT=HREF 
        URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
```

How to perform it?

Comment: It finds the first result that matches with the ATTR

Comment: its not the same because in some cases POS=1 matches with a different POS number from ATTR=CLASS:gift-list-message-action

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need Relative Positioning like this:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:"Send a gift"

TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:gift-list-message-action EXTRACT=HREF 
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
```